# Random value from database column but only one time in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

My database query return random row from database. Is there any way when page load and return this random string when user refresh the page to not change the string?

So this is my controller

```
public function view() {

    $view = View::orderByRaw("RAND()")->limit('1')->get();          

    return View::make('site.view', [
            'view' => $view
        ]);
}
```

And in my blade I have

```
@foreach($view as $rand) 
  {{ Form::open() }}
      {{ $rand['my_view'] }} 

       // bunch of form fealds
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  {{ Form::clode() }}
@endforeach
```

So here user got random string and need to fill the form and add also this string. Then I save all information in database. Everything is saved perfectly in database. The problem is that user can refresh multiple time table after he submit form and can get confused when he see another random string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Option #1 - save the data you got from the `View::make` to a session and return it</strike>:

```
public function view() {
    $rand_view = Session::get('rand_view');
    if (!$rand_view) {
        $view = View::orderByRaw("RAND()")->limit('1')->get();

        $rand_view = View::make('site.view', [
            'view' => $view
        ]);

        Session::put('rand_view', $rand_view);
    }
    return $rand_view;
}
```

Option #2 - for a specific user - always generate the same "random":

```
public function view() {
    // To make sure we generate the same RAND() we generate a random seed for each user and we save that seed in the session for that user.
    $rand_seed = Session::get('rand_seed');
    if (!$rand_seed) {
        $rand_seed = mt_rand();
        Session::put('rand_seed', $rand_seed);
    };

    $view = View::orderByRaw("RAND({$rand_seed})")->limit('1')->get();          

    return View::make('site.view', [
        'view' => $view
    ]);
}
```

### Update

After some debugging it seems like option #1 will not work because `View::make` returns an object that can't be serialized. If you need this solution use option #2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I certainly need Option #1 and tried it but I've got `Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed `

Comment: Do I need to change foreach loop in my view? `@foreach($view as $rand)  ...`

Comment: Sorry, in `option #1`

Comment: There is nothing in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` nothing like empty.. I've deleted current log and reloaded the page -> this error 500 doesn't generate error log

Comment: Also I have in app/config/app.php: `'debug' => true,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124999/discussion-between-dekel-and-garg).

Comment: Option 1 does work just store $view in the session, not the entire $rand_view. This would save an unnecessary trip back to the database.

Comment: No idea what Garg tried, he dropped 2 random lines of code in a comment and claimed that they did not work. Laravel's session can store objects and the collection returned by the get() method is an object. If all else fails, the result of the get() can be persisted as an array and retrieved from there. Queries ending `... order by rand(seed) limit 1` should be avoided (or at least use the MySQL query cache) because they have a huge performance hit on a large table.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the random data into a session variable a display the contents of the session variable if it is present. Just do not forget to unset the variable when it is no longer needed.